# NTFS partition problem

Tags: partition, ntfs

I used Gnome Disks to shrink an NTFS partition, something went wrong and now I can't mount nor boot Windows.
Every time I try to mount it I get this message:

```
Run lists overlap. Cannot merge: Numerical result out of range
ntfs_mapping_pairs_decompress() failed: Numerical result out of range
Failed to load $MFT: Numerical result out of range
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc4': Numerical result out of range
```

What does this mean? What could have happened?

Answer (score 0):

You've seemingly destroyed your partition. Boot into Windows, try running `chkdsk`. Before running `chkdsk` I'd recommend making a full byte to byte copy of the disk because `chkdsk` may make data restoration impossible.

You should probably avoid resizing NTFS partitions using Linux utilities in the future: either use Windows Disk Manager or tools like Acronis Disk Director.